# My proof that there exist no odd 2-cycles for the accelerated Collatz function other than $(1,1)$. Do you have a link to a historical proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, soft-question, collatz-conjecture

Let $f(x) = \dfrac{3x + 1}{2^{\nu_2(3x + 1)}}$.  Clearly the $(1,2,4)$ cycle from the original Collatz map disappears under this context.  So the Collatz conjecture-equivalent goal with $f$ is that there exists no tuples $(x_0, x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ of *odd* natural numbers such that

$$\dfrac{3x_0 + 1}{2^{k_1}} = x_1,  \ \dfrac{3x_1 + 1}{2^{k_2}} = x_2, \ \dots \ , \dfrac{3x_n + 1}{2^{k_0}} = x_0 \tag{1}$$

Notice that the indices wrap around $\pmod n$.

for some $k_i \geq 1$ and $n \geq 1$.  We call such $(x,y)$ a $2$-cycle, and such $(x,y,z,w)$ a $4$-cycle for example, but we also call $(x,y,x,y)$ a $4$-cycle.  Thus $2$-cycles "embed into" $4$-cycles.  Clearly if there are no $k$-cycles (under this definition) then there are no $k'$ cycles for any $1 \lt k' \mid k$.  Anyway, what I wanted to prove was the $2$-cycle Collatz special case.

Suppose that such $x_i, k_i$ existed.  The sequence (1) defines a $2\times 2$ linear system (for the $2$-cycle case $n = 1$):

$$
-3x_0 - 1 + 2^{k_1} x_1 = 0 \\
2^{k_0}x_0 - 3x_1 - 1 = 0
$$

The solution to this linear system is:

$$
\left\{\left( \frac{2^{k_{1}} + 3}{2^{k_{0}} \cdot 2^{k_{1}} - 9}, \  \frac{2^{k_{0}} + 3}{2^{k_{0}} \cdot 2^{k_{1}} - 9}\right)\right\}
$$

That is to say, for each $(k_0, k_1) \in \Bbb{N}^2$ such that the entries to the tuple above are integral, the tuple forms an *odd loop solution* $(x_0,x_1)$, or a $2$-cycle.

Our goal is then to prove that the only possible solution is $(1,1)$.

But, if $(2^{k_0 + k_1} - 9) \mid (2^{k_1} + 3)$ then we have in particular that:

$$
1 \leq 2^{k_0 + k_1} - 9 \leq 2^{k_1} + 3
$$

Now by algebraic rearrangement, we have equivalently:

$$
10 \leq 2^{k_0 + k_1} \\
2^{k_1}(2^{k_0} - 1) \leq 12
$$

Then $k_0 + k_1 \geq 4$ by the first inequality and $2^{k_1} \leq 12$.  Which means $k_1 = 1, 2, 3$ since $k_1 \geq 1$ by definition.  Similarly $(2^{k_0} - 1) \leq 12$ so that $k_0 = 1,2,3$. This completely determines all possibilities for the tuple $(k_0, k_1)$ (that we need to check for a $2$-cycle).

So that the possibilities are:

$$
(1,3),(2,2),(3,1),(2,3),(3,2),(3,3).
$$

We have:

$$
\dfrac{2^{k_1} + 3}{2^{k_0 + k_1} - 9} = \\
(1,3): \dfrac{2^{3} + 3}{2^4 - 9} = \dfrac{11}{7}  \\
(2,2): \dfrac{2^{2} + 3}{2^4 - 9} = \dfrac{7}{7} = 1 \\
(3,1): \dfrac{2^{1} + 3}{2^4 - 9} = \dfrac{5}{7} \\
(2,3): \dfrac{2^{3} + 3}{2^5 - 9} = \dfrac{11}{23} \\
(3,2): \dfrac{2^{2} + 3}{2^5 - 9} = \dfrac{7}{23} \\
(3,3): \dfrac{2^{3} + 3}{2^6 - 9} = \dfrac{11}{55} \\
$$

Since these are first components $x$ of a (rational) loop solution (an odd, accelerated $2$-cycle i.e.) $(x,y)$, you must plug back in and compute $f(x)$ to get $y$.

The only integral (and positive; note the $1\leq \dots$ used in finding them) loop solution is $(1,1)$ and we're done.

There exist no other *odd $2$-cycles* for the *accelerated* Collatz map.  Which is to say, for the original Collatz iterations, there are no (positive) cycles with purely $2$ odd numbers in them.

---

So my question is a soft question and it's *why then, historically, do people say that it was very difficult to prove the $2$-cycle case for Collatz*?  And I can't find any information on that proof, so if you can provide a link for us, that would help out us amateur mathematicians.

Comment: This is important, because if the people quoting history are correct, then what I'm proving is not the same thing as what the historical Collatz proposition entails.

Comment: a "1-cycle" in literature is $a$ successive climb (mult by 3, +1, /2) followed by $b$ successive division by 2. a 2-cycle is 2 successive 1-cycle. Your 2-cycle is $1$ climb followed by 1 or more divisions by 2, twice.

Comment: @Collag3n please rewrite your comment.  I'm not making any sense of it :)  Yeah, also please explain why they would make such a convoluted definition of cycle!  You could also explain their result in terms of my definition of cycle, that might help.

Comment: a "1-cycle" in literature is when you start from $x$, and apply $a$ times $f(x)=\frac{3x+1}{2}$ (until you can't anymore or in other word, you reached an even number), followed by a division by $2^b$ ($b$ being the 2-valuation of your last step)

Comment: I see, then why didn't they use my definition which is conjecturally equivalent but simpler?  I.e. if you prove that no $n$-cycles exist for accelerated Collatz and for all $n \geq 2$, then you've proven the original Collatz conjecture.

Comment: In you definition of a "2-cycle", if $k_1=1$, and $k_0>1$, it would be a "1-cycle"

Comment: @Collag3n is there a standard definition such as mine that is in use, but for the accelerated Collatz?

Comment: There are several definitions of the "Collatz" function (original, shortcut, accelerated), but that is another thing. For k-cycles, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#k-cycles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd propose, you call your "2-cycle" a "2-step-cycle" to avoid misunterstandings: the term "2-cycle" is already in use in the Collatz-discussion and means another thing and has already been disproved (J. Simons, ca 2000).

So, if you agree, I'll take your question as one on the "2-step-cycle":
$$  b = { 3a+1\over 2^A } \qquad \rightarrow a = { 3b+1\over 2^B } \qquad \rightarrow b = { 3a+1\over 2^A }\qquad \rightarrow  \cdots
\tag 1$$
Build the product of the lhs in the above equations as well of the rhs:
$$  b \cdot a = \left({ 3a+1\over 2^A }\right)\cdot\left({ 3b+1\over 2^B }\right) \tag 2
$$
Rearrange
$$ 2^S (=2^{A+B}) = \left(3+{ 1\over a }\right)\cdot\left(3+{1\over b }\right) \tag 3
$$
We see, that the rhs can only get values between $16$ (when $a=b=1$) and $9$ (when $a=b=\infty$). But there are no perfect powers of $2$ between $9$ and $16$ except that which makes the trivial cycle ($a=b=1$) occur.

---

Back to the question, why "2-cycle disproof is difficult". Initially, Ray Steiner in 1976 discussed what he christened the "circuit", and then the "circuit which is also a cycle", whose existence he could then disprove (using "heavy tools" from transcendent number theory (Lagarias)).
This case has been re-christened "1-cycle" by John Simons in ca 2000 to lay ground for generalizations to "2-cycle", "3-cycle",..."k-cycle".
For me, the nicest method to get intuition about this, is my notation
$$  T(a,[A]) := a_2= {3a+1\over 2^A} \\
T(a_1,[A_1,A_2]) :=a_3= {3{3a_1+1\over 2^{A_1}}+1 \over 2^{A_2}} \tag 4
$$
and so on, generalizable to as many exponents $A_k$ as wanted.

With this, Steiner's "circuit which cycles" (and Simon's "1-cycle") is defined by
$$ a_1 = T(a_1,[1,1,1,1,1,...,1,A]) \qquad A\gt 1 \tag 5$$
with as many "1" as you want (I say $N$ for the (N)umber of all exponents/steps and $S$ for their (S)um).

It has been much difficult to find an argument, that no such "1-cycle" exist except that with no exponents $1$ and only $A=2$: $ 1 = T(1,[2]) $ (and only in the negative numbers $-1 = T(-1,[1]) $ and $-5=T(-5,[1,2])$ ).

The "2-cycle" is now a construction
$$ a_1 = T(a_1,[1,1,1,1,1,...,1,A,1,1,1....,1,B]) \qquad A,B\gt 1 \tag 6$$ with as many "1" you want in each sub-trajectory, and J. Simons needed a dozen-page paper to do the disproof in the analoguous style as R. Steiner had it invented.
Generalizing this, J. Simons ( & B.de Weger) could come up with disproofs of "k-cycles" up to $k=68$ (or $74$, I'm not up-to-date).

What is, btw., not so well known is that the third known cycle in the negative numbers beginning at $-17$ is a nice, true "2-cycle" having, if I don't err $-17=T(-17,[1,1,1,2,1,1,4])$ (and I like this small fact as a little gem in all this discussions :-) ).

---

*update* I forgot, I have a very old workout of this (and a bit more) when I've learned this things myself in 2004. Perhaps you find even more impulses for further thinking/fiddling in that pages/subpages. See [subsections on "loops"](https://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/aboutloop/collloopintro_main.htm) on my homepage.